# Possibly redundant code in RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

Yesterday I've written this strange interface designed to encapsulate some request to backend. I wrote it because I had to pass some subset of server objects outside and outside code should have ability to repeat this request as many times as it sees fit without knowing any details about how this subset is formed. But could just reinvent the wheel. Did I?

```
export interface IQuery<E> {
  (): Observable<E>;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Obviously, each invokation of this method performs request to server and returns an Observable. I need this interface because I know how to do this request only in place A and I have to actually do it only in place B, usually many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'd say you created a redundant interface.  You can just as easily have your API return an `Observable<E>`.

Why?  Because your API implementation can just return a cold Observable by wrapping the function using [Observable.defer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer):

```
function apiMethod(arg1: any) : Observable<Result> {
   // use defer to create an observable which will re-query
   // each time someone subscribes to it.
   return Observable.defer(() => doTheQuery(arg1, privateObject));
}

o = apiMethod("a"); // does not execute query
o.subscribe(...); // execute query
o.subscribe(...); // execute query again
```

You get the same benefits you are seeking (encapsulation) without requiring the consumer to work with yet another interface.  The callers can do all the observable stuff they might ever want to do, like compose your server observable with other observables.

If you were to keep the interface you have, then consumers might end up doing:

```
function wrapApi(query: IQuery<E>) : Observable<E> {
   return Observable.defer(() => query());
}

o = wrapApi(yourApi.someQuery(a, b, c));
o.subscribe(...); // execute query
o.subscribe(...); // execute query again
```

Why make them do that?